# How can i set dynamic data in below treeview using Javascript or ES6

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

> Note - In this example i have created treeview with details and summary tags with static data and its work perfect but now how can we set n level dynamic data with javascript or ES6 for this treeview and dynamic data is like json or array, so please help me or give me solution to set dynamic data inside this treeview.

```css
html {
     height: 100%;
}
 body {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     min-height: 100%;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     margin: auto;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     max-width: 350px;
}
 * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body > details {
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 body > details summary {
     color: white;
     padding: 8px;
     background-color: #174378;
     border: 1px solid #174378;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
 body > details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
     margin-right: 14px;
}
 body > details > details {
     margin: 5px 0;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position: relative;
}
 body > details > details::after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: -5px;
     left: -10px;
     width: 1px;
     height: calc(36px + 10px);
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 body > details > details:last-child::after {
     height: calc(36px / 2 + 5px);
}
 body > details > details::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: calc(36px / 2);
     left: -10px;
     width: 8px;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 body > details > details[open]:not(:last-child)::after {
     height: calc(100% + 5px);
}
 body > details > details summary {
     color: white;
     padding: 8px;
     background-color: #174378;
     border: 1px solid #174378;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
 body > details > details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
     margin-right: 14px;
}
 body > details > details > details {
     margin: 5px 0;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position: relative;
}
 body > details > details > details::after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: -5px;
     left: -10px;
     width: 1px;
     height: calc(28px + 10px);
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 body > details > details > details:last-child::after {
     height: calc(28px / 2 + 5px);
}
 body > details > details > details::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: calc(28px / 2);
     left: -10px;
     width: 8px;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 body > details > details > details[open]:not(:last-child)::after {
     height: calc(100% + 5px);
}
 body > details > details > details summary {
     margin: 5px 0;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     background-color: #dfe7ec;
     border: 1px solid #c7d3df;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: #545f69;
     position: relative;
}
 body > details > details > details summary span {
     color: #041320;
}
 ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 li {
     margin: 5px 0;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     background-color: #dfe7ec;
     border: 1px solid #c7d3df;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: #545f69;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 15px;
     position: relative;
}
 li span {
     color: #041320;
}
 li::after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: -5px;
     left: -10px;
     width: 1px;
     height: calc(28px + 10px);
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 li:last-child::after {
     height: calc(28px / 2 + 5px);
}
 li::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: calc(28px / 2);
     left: -10px;
     width: 8px;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #c7d3df;
}
 li[open]:not(:last-child)::after {
     height: calc(100% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<details open>
  <summary>Pick-up containers</summary>
  <details>
    <summary>Unit 1</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Fixed field:</span> fixed field text</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
  <details open>
    <summary>Unit 2</summary>
     <details open>
       <summary><span>Group field label:</span> group field text</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Fixed field:</span> fixed field text</li>
      <li><span>License plate:</span> 1-XTM-289</li>
      <li><span>BAT number:</span> 123912301938</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
     <details>
       <summary><span>Group field label:</span> group field text</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Fixed field:</span> fixed field text</li>
      <li><span>License plate:</span> 1-XTM-289</li>
      <li><span>BAT number:</span> 123912301938</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Unit 3</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Fixed field:</span> fixed field text</li>
      <li><span>License plate:</span> 1-XTM-289</li>
      <li><span>BAT number:</span> 123912301938</li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</details>
```